# Fill select on app init intel xdk

Tags: select, intel-xdk

In www/js/init-apps.js I have established communication with server and retrieved data needed to fill select. On page #mainpage I have a select I would like the options to be the retrieved data. How do I fill the options list on #mainpage from init-apps.js or do I need to put a button on #mainpage and fill from there? So far I have not come up with a way to do it from init-app.js this the way I would prefer to fill the select. That way when app shows select will be filled and all user has to do is make selection, enter username and password and login in.

Answer (score 0):

```
// var leagues = "";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status == 200)    {
        leagues = xhr.responseText;
        // app.consoleLog(fName,leagues) ;
        var slen2 = leagues.indexOf('``'); // inserted in my php program 
        if (slen2 > 0) {
            while (leagues.length > 0) {
                var slen = leagues.indexOf('``');
                var leag = leagues.substring(0,slen);
                var slen3 = leagues.indexOf('^^'); // inserted in my php program 
                var _id = leagues.substring(slen+2,slen3);
                $('#leagueid').append($("<option value= "+_id+">"+leag+"</option>"));
                leagues = leagues.substr(slen3+2, leagues.length );
            } 
        }
    }
    else if(xhr.status == 404)
   {
       navigator.notification.alert("Web Service Doesn't Exist", "Error");
   }
   else
   {
       navigator.notification.alert("Unknown error occured while connecting to server", "Error");
   }
};
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.?????.com/dartleague/?????.php?my??=0");
xhr.send(); 
// #leagueid is ID of the select control
```